# How to show an image when loading Application in Android?

Tags: android, image, download

I am building an Android app.

For that i want to show image at the time of starting ( like in iPhone when we start app it shows download image after downloading completed it will disappear. )

**Edit** If user click on my app icon for loading it takes some time , in this time i want to show an image..

Is it possible in Android , if yes guide me how to do this.

**SlashScreen**

Comment: you mean to say like splash screen ?

Comment: Search SplashScreen implementation in android.

Comment: Please elaborate more about your question or some example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see link:

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-make-a-basic-splash-screen/

Comment: when i run this i am getting this error : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException , i am using android 2.2

Answer (score 1):

I figure you want the UI to not have any lagg right? So what you want to do is do all this "loading" business in a different thread from your UI, what is it your application wants to load?

Have a look at this article: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Or maybe have a look at this: http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-make-a-basic-splash-screen/

It may help you out, but you might want to elaborate on what you are trying to do so we can help out more.

---

What I believe you should do tho is delay this loading until you have loaded this splash screen. You should display something like a progress bar so the user doesn't see your app as if it was freezing.

You should look into AsyncTask (right down the bottom of that thread)

Answer (score 0):

The above link: http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-make-a-basic-splash-screen/ is dead
please use following link to get the details:

http://web.archive.org/web/20130115075557/http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-make-a-basic-splash-screen/

Comment: and the source file here: https://niitict.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4/SplashDemo.rar